# PHP parent method override not working (using namespaces)

Tags: php, inheritance, methods, namespaces, overriding

I have three different files for each part of code. (i use class autoloader). 
First file (/classes/Test/Foo.php):

```
<?php
namespace Test;

class Foo
{
  public $id;

  function __construct(int $id)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function get() : string
  {
    return "FOO:" . $this->id;
  }
}
```

Second file (/classes/Test/Bar.php):

```
<?php
namespace Test;

class Bar extends Foo
{
  public function get() : string
  {
    return "BAR:" . $this->id;
  } 
}
```

Third file (/index.php):

```
<?php
namespace Test;
include "autoloader.php";
$bar = new Bar(1);
echo $bar->get();
```

When i execute third file i didn't get any output at all, not even error
...but if i put all code in one file it works.

```
<?php
namespace Test;

class Foo
{
  public $id;

  function __construct(int $id)
  {
    $this->id = $id;
  }

  public function get() : string
  {
    return "FOO:" . $this->id;
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo
{
  public function get() : string
  {
    return "BAR:" . $this->id;
  } 
}

$bar = new Bar(1);
echo $bar->get();
```

output: BAR:1

What could be the problem?

Autoloader code:

```
<?php
spl_autoload_register(function($class) {
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/classes/" . str_replace("\\", "/", $class) . ".php";
});
```

Comment: Did you include your PHP file?

Comment: What's error code?

Comment: You say you're using a class autoloader but I don't see you actually registering it anywhere

Comment: none, just blank screen.

Comment: For blank screen, please check your php error log or enable error reporting for your script: error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get PHP errors to display?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display)

Comment: Error reporting is on

Comment: Please include your autoloader.

Comment: autoloader included in third file, or you mean code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem! This code was example, but in actual code, overridden method had different return type (int instead of string).

Answer (score 0):

The file path required in your autoloader will reflect the classname **including the namespace** - this needs to exactly match the directory structure on disk.

Within the callback to `spl_autoload_register`, `$class` will first be passed in as **Test\Bar**. This results in it attempting to include the file **classes/Test/Bar.php**, which doesn't exist. This will be throwing a fatal error - it sounds like your error reporting settings aren't configured to display this.

For the files you've posted, your directory structure needs to look like this:

```
.
├── classes
│   └── Test
│       ├── Bar.php
│       └── Foo.php
├── autoloader.php
└── index.php
```

Comment: i fogot to wite description correctly, but directory structure is same as you described